# Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I keep getting this error from my code and I have no idea what I am doing wrong, this happens on occasions and it seems to work when it wants to

**error**

```
 Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\P\Find.php on line 265
```

I've basically created a crawler which searches a webpage for an element on the webpage, sometimes this element may not be present on the page, and I check for this by using the if statement.

line 265 refers to

```
if($page->find('div#olpDivId span.price'))
```

**code**

```
   $page = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0304362212');

   if($page->find('div#olpDivId span.price')){
        foreach($page->find('div#olpDivId span.price') as $p){
            $i[] = floatval($p->plaintext);                 
        }
    }
```

if the book does not exist the crawler goes to a blank "sorry product does not exist" page
Am I doing something wrong? any help would be appreciated

Comment: show us how you set the value of `$page`.

Comment: If you forgot to initialize `$page` as an object, that would explain the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with $page

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with `$page`.  What if your http request fails, what do you think `$page` gets set to then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_html` can return false (if it was unable to fetch content from webpage), so you should check for it before using any method on `$page`

```
$page = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0304362212');

if($page !== FALSE){
    foreach($page->find('div#olpDivId span.price') as $p){
        $i[] = floatval($p->plaintext);                 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I should have taken that into consideration, if it does fail do you think it would be a good idea to recall the method?

Comment: it depends on what was the cause of fail. If your bot was banned because of to excessive crawling, making it repeat won't work, and can only make it worse. But on the other hand, it can by temporary problem with server/network and second request may be successful. You may try getting page content by curl and checking response headers to have better info of failed request.